# Printing textbox input to console with tkinter (python3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, printing

I am making tic tac toe in python using tkinter, and the code all works except for when I try to print which player is the winner, I get the following ouput:

```
The player who won is:  
.!entry
```

The code I used to print out the winner is this:

```
        print("The player who won is: ", e1_entry)
        ...
```

where `e1_entry` is defined as this:

```
e1_entry = e1.get()
```

and e1 is:

```
e1 = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=e1_entry)
```

How would I make it so that the text taken from the tkinter `Entry` is printed to the console?

Thanks

Gaurav Bhalla

Comment: Which console are you referring to?

Comment: @PedroLobito I mean the console that is printed to when you call the `print()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try something like:

```
window = Tk()
text = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable = text)
e1.pack()
e1_entry = text.get()
print("The player who won is:", e1_entry)
```

Comment: There is a problem. It will instantly print the bottom line of code and not wait for user entry. Therefore, this won't work.

Comment: @SanguineL it's fine because I have put that line in the function that checks for a winner.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a working example. You would need to define a function to get the string

```
import tkinter


def getWinner():
    n = entry1.get()

    if n == "":
        n = "Nobody won"

    print(n)

root = tkinter.Tk()

entry1 = tkinter.Entry(root)
entry1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

root.after(10000, getWinner)

root.mainloop()
```

This has an Entry widget, and after 10 seconds, will call the function 'getWinner'. If the Entry widget has no text in it, there will be no winner.

Hope this helps!